# How to post in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, textarea

I am in trouble with this very simple jQuery code.

I have a textarea and a button to post comments. Whenever i post a comment then textarea's value is going to be listed.

**HTML**

```
 <textarea rows="5" cols="40" class="Textarea"></textarea>
<ul>
    <li class="comment_list"></li></ul>    
<input type="button"  value="Post" class="button_post"/>
```

I am using this **jQuery code-**

```
$(function(){

var text_t=$(".Textarea").val();
$(".button_post").click(function(){
$(" .comment_list").val(text_t);

});
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FGwYn/)

Comment: What is the question/problem?

Comment: @undefined, I suppose the question title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $(".button_post").click(function () {
        var text_t = $(".Textarea").val(); 
        // text_t has to be in the click function it order for it to update with the new content when you click post (otherwise it will be empty like the textbox was when the page loaded)
        $(".comment_list").text(text_t); // li does not have a value, use html() or text()
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FGwYn/1/)

---

### More details

```
$(function(){
var text_t=$(".Textarea").val();
```

First of all doing the above will load the value of the `textbox` when the document is ready, thus `text_t` will be empty in your case (the textbox has no value when the page loads)

```
$(".button_post").click(function(){
   $(".comment_list").val(text_t);
});
```

The second problem comes here, `li` does not have a value attribute so you cannot use `.val()`. What you can use is `.text()` (which will insert a text between `<li></li>`, or `.html()` for html structure).

Here to note that since `text_r` is outside the click function, it will not update to the new textbox value when you click post.

```
}); // end
```

Comment: Add an explanation to the op why his work doesn't work and it's a +1

Comment: @PatsyIssa hope I summed it all now

Comment: @Spokey, Many confusions omitted today, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Right way is:

```
$(function () {    
    $(".button_post").click(function () {
        var text_t = $("textarea").val();                
        $(".comment_list").html(text_t);
    });
});
```

Put your '`var text_t = $("textarea").val();`' inside function not outside because by your code **var text_t** being assign with blank val.

Comment: That is identical to @spokey's answer 10 minutes ago except you use the tag rather than the class and html instead of text

Comment: @mplungjan; nope, he run very fast :)